# Replace Selection option with image and text in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I am trying to replace the option of select with some image and text but didn't succeeded.My select code as follow:

```
    <select class="te-combo"><option value="">Select Language</option>
<option value="en">English</option><option value="zh-TW">Chinese</option>
<option value="fr">French</option><option value="de">German</option>
</select>
```

My js code is :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery("document").ready(function() {
 jQuery('select option:contains("English")').text('<span class="l_name">English</span><img alt="English" width="30" height="30" title="English" src="images/flags/en_US.png">');
});

        </script>
```

The select Field is also created using js code.

Comment: You can't, it's that simple! If you want images you'll have to create your own custom dropdown made up of other elements than select and option, the only other option is background images, but not sure if that is cross-browser.

Comment: Any alternative ? so that i can load image instead of text

Comment: What part of `you can't` was unclear? You have to create a custom dropdown from UL and LI elements, or try background images and see if it works in all browsers, I don't think it will.

Answer (score 0):

See following example. It uses a library [ddslick](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick)

www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2014/04/jquery-custom-dropdown-with-images-ddslick-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

The only content permitted inside an `<option>` is text (see *Permitted content* in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)). If you want a drop-down with images, you cannot use `<select>` and will need to choose some of the plethora libraries providing this functionality.